# Get current canvas of a control xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation

I have a double animation which worked well on one control. Now I want to make it universal. How do I get current canvas of a control? For example I want to use this animation on window and it always showed from 13 to 17 while I need from 'current position' to 'current position + 4'

```
<BeginStoryboard x:Key="SomethingWrongAnimation">
        <Storyboard  Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)">
            <DoubleAnimation From="13" To="17" Duration="0:0:0.05" 
                         AutoReverse="True" FillBehavior="Stop" RepeatBehavior="5x"/>
        </Storyboard>
    </BeginStoryboard>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `From` and `To` set the `By` property:

```
<DoubleAnimation By="4" ... />
```

Comment: Thank you it works!! And what about from current-2 to current +2?

Comment: And i can't use "By" for window:( only from to

Comment: There is an exception

Comment: What does it mean when you say "for window"? Your animation animates the `Canvas.Left` attached property, which only has an effect if the target of the animation is a child of a Canvas, and if the value of the property has been initialized to something different than its default value `NaN`.